# Proving that the following bilinear map is well defined.

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let M be a compact differentiable manifold of dimension n. Show that the bilinear map $H_{dR}^s(M,\mathbb{R}) \times H_{dR}^{n - s}(X,\mathbb,R) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $([v],[w]) \mapsto \int_{M} v \wedge w$ is well defined.

I was thinking maybe I could use stokes theorem but I am not sure. 
Here is what I have so far to prove this is well defined we have to do it for each of the component.

Suppose that $[v] = [v_1]$ then $v_1 = v + d\sigma$. Then $[v_1,w] \mapsto \int_{M} (v + d\sigma) \wedge w) = \int_M(v \wedge w) + \int_M(d\sigma \wedge w)$. Why is $\int_{M}(d\sigma \wedge w) = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you want to use Stokes's Theorem, remembering that $\partial M = \emptyset$. Note that $w$ is a closed form so $d(\sigma\wedge w) = d\sigma\wedge w$.